# Clean install - Changing permalinks in twentyeleven give 404

Tags: permalinks, pagination, 404-error, theme-twenty-eleven

interesting problem that I encountered, not sure if it's bug or not..

On a clean install using the **twentyeleven** theme I try changing the *Permalink Settings* to something different from the *Deffault* and every post starts giving Page Not Found 404.
The Pagination and the top Nav Menu also stop working.

What needs to be changed for all of this to start working, because the same problem is present when I start creating custom theme?

EDIT: Figured it out! The solution was very simple - turning the *rewrite module* of WAMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure your .htaccess file (in the root) is writable by WordPress, if it isn't then you may need to manually set this up to get the permalinks working correctly.

Comment: I checked it, and it's not _Read-Only_. Or you meant something different?

Comment: Thanks for turning my attention toward the .htaccess file. The _rewrite module_ of WAMP wasn't turned on. I kept searching the source of the error in other places..